# php extract all hashtags and twitter names from a block of text

Tags: php

I have a block of text in php, and I want to be able to extract all hashtags and twitter names from it, and print them as one new string.

For example:

```
$longstring = "blah blah blah #hashtag blah blah @twittername blah email@email.com blah blah #hashtag2 blah blah";
```

And I want to create one new string:

```
$extracted = "#hashtag @twittername #hashtag2";
```

Any idea how I can do this easily?

I'm not sure if the answer is a regex? Can that do both together and find all multiple occurrences of both types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match_all` solution:

```
$longstring = "blah blah blah #hashtag blah blah @twittername blah email@email.com blah blah #hashtag2 blah blah";
preg_match_all("/(?:^|\s)[#@][^ @#]+\b/", $longstring, $m);
$extracted = implode("", $m[0]);

print_r($extracted);
```

The output:

```
#hashtag @twittername #hashtag2
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help you out.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/w0Nlyg/7)

**Regex:** `#[^\s]+|(?<=\s|^)@[^\s@#]+`

> **1.** `#[^\s]+` this will match `#` and then match all till `space`(not including space)
>
> **2.** `|` or
>
> **3.** `(?<=\s|^)@[^\s@#]+` match `@` and then `all` except `space`, `@` and `#` with positive look behind for `space` or `start of string`

Here we are using `preg_match_all` for gathering matches and `implode` for joining it as string.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/795028)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = "blah blah blah #hashtag blah blah @twittername blah email@email.com blah blah #hashtag2 blah blah";
preg_match_all("/#[^\s]+|(?<=\s|^)@[^\s@#]+/", $string, $matches);
print_r(implode(" ",$matches[0]));
```

**Output:**
`#hashtag @twittername #hashtag2`

Answer (score 3):

The following code will work for you:
Here first we split the sentence by spaces.

Then we check is the word starts with an "@" or "#".

If yes then we append it to the new string.

```
<?php
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}
$longstring = "blah blah blah #hashtag blah blah @twittername blah email@email.com blah blah #hashtag2 blah blah";
$parts = explode(" ",$longstring);
$newString = "";
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    if(startsWith($part, "#") || startsWith($part, "@"))
    {
        $newString.= $part." ";
    }
}

echo $newString;
```